# implement delivery system using google map services

Tags: android, google-maps

I am devloping an android app for my college project.
And i am new to android devlopment.

i am devloping a simple m-commerce app.

for this i am able to access the location of user .

but i am unable to list all the vendors available for delivering that product to that lat long position.

1)basically i wannt to define any polygon or any circle on the map and user whoose lat long is inside that polygon/circle will see the list of all vendors inside that area.

2)or something like drawing a circle around the user by taking his lat long position as centre and taking some radius x and and show him all the vendor who are inside the circle .

i have seen some tutorial in which they shown how to draw shapes on the map.

but i am quiet confused how to implement my idea 1 0r 2 .

please guide me and if posible please refer me some good course material for android devlopment.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");     
locationA.setLatitude(latA); 
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);
Location locationB = new Location("point B");
locationB.setLatitude(latB); 
LocationB.setLongitude(lngB);
distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB) ;
```

this is the code to calculate the distance between two latlon in meters according to this you can calculate the users inside circle.